# Events firing from an unloaded Page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

In my UWP app I have 2 Pages that both have an instance of a custom ListView. When the first Page is unloaded out of the Frame, the second Page is immediately loaded into it. Also, the ListViews in both Pages have a SelectionChanged event that is x:Binded to an event handler located in the MainViewModel. With me so far?

The problem occurs when I navigate from one Page to another and then select items in the ListView. Somehow, the SelectionChanged event gets calls twice. I came to realize that the ListView in the unloaded Page is also firing the SelectionChanged event, even though I'm not on that Page and, therefore, I'm not selecting any items on that Page! Weird. Hope I made some sort of sense here.

```
    <!-- Page1.xaml -->
    <TemplatedControls:MyListView x:Name="MyListView"
                                  SelectionChanged="{x:Bind MainViewModel.MyListView_SelectionChanged}">
    </TemplatedControls:MyListView>

    <!-- Page2.xaml -->
    <TemplatedControls:MyListView x:Name="MyListView"
                                  SelectionChanged="{x:Bind MainViewModel.MyListView_SelectionChanged}">
    </TemplatedControls:MyListView>
```

Comment: I have now come to learn that this issue disappears after the garbage collector runs and frees the previous Page's resources or whatever. But this is still strange and I would like to know of the most efficient way to deal with this problem.

Comment: I created two pages those bind the same `viewmodel`. But I could not reproduce your issue. Could you share a sample simple?

Answer (score 1):

> I have now come to learn that this issue disappears after the garbage collector runs and frees the previous `Page`'s resources or whatever. But this is still strange and I would like to know of the most efficient way to deal with this problem.

This is actually the expected behaviour. When you subscribe to an event using the weak event pattern (like UWP obviously does), the event handling continues until the garbage collecor collects the listener: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/weak-event-patterns

If you want to be able to control exactly when to unsubscribe from the event, you could override the `On​Navigating​From` method and unsubscribe explicitly:

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyListView.SelectionChanged += MainViewModel.MyListView_SelectionChanged;
}
    ...

    protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        MyListView.SelectionChanged -= MainViewModel.MyListView_SelectionChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can agree this is a solution, but it still does not explain, why a different instance of the list view control executes the method twice. As you data bound `SelectionChanged` of a different instance of the list view, why does that particular list view fire the method? I bet it will be some `x:Bind` magic under the hood, but I don't see it right now.